# declare Object with the same key names

Tags: javascript, object, declare

Is there a way to declare a Object with the same key names in js ?

```
let Obj = {
   '1' : '1',
   '1' : '1',
   '1' : '1',
}
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. Use an array of objects.

Comment: how would you know than what data to access ?

Comment: yes, you declare it exactly like that - you end up with one `1` though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The names of the properties in an object must be unique, not least so you can identify the property you want to get/set. Although the code you wrote will parse and run, the resulting object will have only **one** property (the last one using that name):

```js
let obj = {
    1: "first",
    1: "second",
    1: "third",
};
console.log(obj[1]);; // "third"
```

You could use an array of objects if the key name must be the same:

```
let array = [
    {1: 1},
    {1: 1},
    {1: 1},
];
```

...or, really, just an array (`let array = [1, 1, 1];`) as the key name isn't doing anything useful if it's always the same.